# How to make button responsive on both Ipad 13.0.1 expo and 12.0.1 in React-Native app

Tags: react-native, button, axios, expo, asyncstorage

i'm new to expo i'm working on app in which signup button is working fine but apple is rejecting my app due to button is not responding at there end but in my ipad 12.0.1 button is working it is taking small time but working here is my code.

```
 axios
        .post(`${serverIp}/users/signin`, postData)
        .then
    (({ data }) => {
            const { isSuccess, error, message } = data;
            this.setState({ buttonDisabled: false ,loading: true});
            if (!isSuccess) {
              // Alert.alert("success")

                this.setState({
                    message: isArabic() ? message : error,
                    messageType: 'error'
                });
            } else {
               // Alert.alert("fail")
                AsyncStorage.setItem(
                    'accessToken',
                    `${data.data.token}`
                ).then(() => {
                    AsyncStorage.setItem('userId', `${data.data.id}`).then( 
                        () => {
                            AsyncStorage.setItem(
                                'lastFlow',
                                'signedIn'
                            ).then(() => {
                                this.setState({
                                    username: '',
                                    password: ''
                                });
                                navigation.navigate('HomeScreen');
                            });


       style    <TabularButton
                                buttonDisabled={buttonDisabled}
                                viewStyles={tabularButtonStyles}
                                textStyles={tabularButtonTextStyles}
                                onPress={() => {
                                    this.signInButton();
                                }}
                                buttonText={signInButton}
                            />

                       tabularButtonStyles: {
               paddingHorizontal: 100,
                marginTop: 20,
               backgroundColor: colors.primary
               },
              tabularButtonTextStyles: {
              color: 'white',
              fontWeight: 'bold',
              paddingVertical: 10
              },
```

Any help will be appreciated. Here is the message i'm apple is sending rejection message We discovered one or more bugs in your app when reviewed on iPad running iOS 13.1.3 on Wi-Fi.

Sign in button not responsive.

Comment: Can you post full code of component or expo snack example?

Comment: this is a very big project

Comment: i can't post full code but i can post full class for you is you want

Comment: https://snack.expo.io/@shabnam.macrew/groaning-popcorn

Comment: In first look, why you put state loading : true in then of axios and not before calling for request and have you some indicator of loading state in ui I try to see your expo snack again if will run, did you run the expo snack that provided?

Comment: this is just one class this will not run i have made that just for your idea how the code is going on  yeah that my mistake i'll remove loading : true coz i have added just to see nothing else plzz ignore that

Comment: if you can show the problem in emulator remotely i will try to help you.

Comment: sure...........

Comment: Have you anydesk access?